# Undefined Es6 class in unit test with gulp mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I'm having some troubles with the following Reference Error while running my unit tests where i can not figure what i did wrong.

First, i've defined the following class:

```
/**
 * Invitation class
 */
export default class Invitation {

  /**
   * Create a Invitation
   * @param {string} user The user id
   * @param {string} creationDate The creation date of the invitation
   * @param {string} validationDate The validation date of the invitation
   * @param {string} denyDate The deny date of the invitation
   * @param {string} project The project id
   * @param {string} userTargetEmail The email address where the invitation was send
   * @param {string} _id The invitation _id
   */
  constructor(user, project, userTargetEmail, creationDate, validationDate, denyDate, _id) {
    /** @type {string} */
    this.user = user;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.validationDate = validationDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.denyDate = denyDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this._id = _id;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.project = project;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.userTargetEmail = userTargetEmail;
  }
}
```

and then the following unit test file (problem occurs in the before each hook):

```
    import Mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import InvitationController from '../../../../../app/business/invitations/controller/InvitationController';
    import InvitationService from '../../../../../app/business/invitations/service/InvitationService';
    import ErrorList from '../../../../../app/helper/ErrorList';
    import NotificationService from '../../../../../app/helper/service/NotificationService';
    import MailService from '../../../../../app/helper/service/mail/op/MailService';
    import RegexService from '../../../../../app/helper/service/RegexService';
    import UserService from '../../../../../app/business/user/service/UserService';
    import User from '../../../../../app/business/user/model/User';
    import ProjectService from '../../../../../app/business/projects/service/ProjectService';
    import Project from '../../../../../app/business/projects/model/Project';
    import UtilService from '../../../../../app/helper/service/UtilService';
    import Invitation from '../../../../../app/business/invitations/model/Invitation';

    let chai = require('chai');
    let sinon = require('sinon');
    let expect = chai.expect;

    /** @test {InvitationController} */
    describe('InvitationController ', () => {
      let controller;
      let mailService;
      let notificationService;
      let invitationService;
      let regexService;
      let userService;
      let projectService;
      let utilService;

      let mockMailService;
      let mockNotifService;
      let mockInvService;
      let mockProjectService;
      let mockUserService;

      let project;
      let userId;
      let projectId;
      let invitationId;
      let user;

      beforeEach(() => {
        invitationId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000007');
        projectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000005');
        userId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');

        mailService = new MailService();
        notificationService = new NotificationService();
        invitationService = new InvitationService();
        regexService = new RegexService();
        userService = new UserService();
        projectService = new ProjectService();
        utilService = new UtilService();

        mockMailService = sinon.mock(mailService);
        mockNotifService = sinon.mock(notificationService);
        mockInvService = sinon.mock(invitationService);
        mockProjectService = sinon.mock(projectService);
        mockUserService = sinon.mock(userService);

        console.log('Loggin Invitation ', Invitation);

        let invitation = new Invitation(userId, projectId, 'mail@mail.fr', 'creationdate', null, null, invitationId);

        console.log('logging invit ', invitation);
        project = new Project('name', 'creationDate', 'lastModificationDate', 'user', projectId);
        user = new User('mail', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', '1');
        controller = new InvitationController(invitationService, projectService, regexService, mailService, notificationService, userService, utilService);
      });
/// all tests
```

And there things goes bad, when i'm runing my tests, i get :

```
  InvitationController
    addInvitationAction
Loggin Invitation function Invitation(user,project,userTargetEmail,creationDate,validationDate,denyDate,_id){__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.f['2']++;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['6']++;_classCallCheck(this,Invitation);__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['7']++;this.user=user;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['8']++;this.creationDate=creationDate;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['9']++;this.validationDate=validationDate;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['10']++;this.denyDate=denyDate;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['11']++;this._id=_id;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['12']++;this.project=project;__cov_Thbl4xwtVLP9GaZCsEH5nQ.s['13']++;this.userTargetEmail=userTargetEmail;}
      1) "before each" hook for "Expect to return an error when projectService.getProjectFromId fail"
...
/// ALL OTHER TESTS LOGS
...
     1) InvitationController  "before each" hook for "Expect to return an error when projectService.getProjectFromId fail":
     ReferenceError: Invitation is not defined
      at new Invitation (C:\Users\gayard\Documents\Dev\MYPROJECT\src\app\business\invitations\model\Invitation.js:9:684)
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:/Users/gayard/Documents/Dev/MYPROJECT/src/test/unit/business/invitations/controller/TestInvitationController-spec.js:64:22)
      at callFn (C:\Users\gayard\Documents\Dev\MYPROJECT\node_modules\gulp-mocha\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:315:21)
      at Hook.Runnable.run (C:\Users\gayard\Documents\Dev\MYPROJECT\node_modules\gulp-mocha\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
      at next (C:\Users\gayard\Documents\Dev\MYPROJECT\node_modules\gulp-mocha\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:298:10)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\gayard\Documents\Dev\MYPROJECT\node_modules\gulp-mocha\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

The import paths are all valid (i've double checked them, and used an atom plugin to make sure they were correct).

At first i suspected a wrong import in the controller, but it wasn't, in fact, it doesn't even reach there, since it doesn't even log the 'logging invit' + invitation.

I have multiple other class imports in the app that i did the exact same way without any troubles, and i'm not able to figure what's happening. I've even tried to rename/rewrite it, but no chances.

Any idea on why Invitation goes undefined even when i'm able to log it before calling for a `new Invitation()`?

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours of testing, i've come to the conclusion :

DO NOT use 'Invit' string in a class name. I do not know why, but on my setup, i keep getting the reference error. I've tried many different names, 'Invi' (works), 'Yolo' (works), 'Invit' (doesn't work), 'InvitationModel' (doesn't work), and the list goes on...

Finally, After rewriting it, the class is now called Call ass follow :

```
/**
 * Call class
 * (invitation model, CAN NOT be named invitation, it's generating References Errors in the unit tests)
 */
export default class Call {
  /**
   * Create a Call
   * @param {string} user the id of the user sending the invitation
   * @param {string} creationDate the creation date of the invitation
   * @param {string} validationDate the validation date of the invitation
   * @param {string} denyDate the deny date of the invitation
   * @param {string} project the project id for wich the invitation has been sent
   * @param {string} userTargetEmail the email address of the target
   * @param {string} _id the notification's id
   */
  constructor(user, creationDate, validationDate, denyDate, project, userTargetEmail, _id) {
    /** @type {string} */
    this.user = user;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.validationDate = validationDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.denyDate = denyDate;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.project = project;
    /** @type {string} */
    this.userTargetEmail = userTargetEmail;
    /** @type {string} */
    this._id = _id;
  }
}
```

This works. Still, i don't know why, so, if somebody ever happen to have an answer to it, i would be really happy to hear it, since it's kind of an unsatisfying workaround.